# sitemap.xml: Should mailto: and tel: links be included?

Tags: sitemap

I'm building a sitemap.xml, and trying out a few generators.

One of the generators kept phone links ("tel:") while excluding email links ("mailto:"). I suspect the generator developer just didn't account for tel:'s.

In any case, is having mailto: or tel: links in the sitemap.xml a bad thing?

For example:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.mywebsite.com/tel:+15551234567</loc>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't hurt for sure if opening this URL in a browser displays a proper page. Else, you will get a notification in Google Search Console (which does not really hurt).